# Why can't we fly aeroplane or shuttle directly into the space (beyond 100 km height above Earth's surface)?

Tags: rocket-science, aircraft, propulsion, space-travel

Without rockets can we go beyond Karmans line by shuttle or plane?

Comment: Might [space.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: A shuttle is a rocket.  That being said [This XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/) probably answers the questions quite well.